# The bat smashed INTO my face

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

In the following sentence, why does the speaker add the word *into*?

> The bat (baseball bat) smashed **into** my face with such force that it crushed my nose into a distorted U-shape.

Answer (score 3):

*Smashed my face* describes the result of the collision: your face was smashed (like a plate might be smashed). However, *smashed **into my face*** describes the trajectory of the bat (and also the intensity of the impact).

The Complement of *smash* in the first sentence is a noun phrase (NP) functioning as Direct Object: *my face*.

The Complement of *smash* in the second sentence is a preposition phrase (PP) telling us about a *path*, a direction of travel: *into my face*.

Answer (score 0):

**Into** is a preposition of motion.

The bat (baseball bat) smashed into my face = The bat (baseball bat) was moving when it hit my face

**In** is locative - a preposition of place.

The bat (baseball bat) smashed in my face = the place that the bat broke was my face.

Consider

He walked **into** the room = He entered the room -> motion.

He walked **in** the room = He was inside the room (place) and he was walking.